# Custom Authorize attribute using session variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp-classic, custom-attributes

I've got a classic asp website running inside an MVC 4 application.  So to access areas of the classic asp website the user needs to log in using a classic asp login page.  At this point they are authenticated within the system.  Their `userid, security level and authentication` are stored in the classic asp session variables.

I then have the log in information from the session put into the ASP.Net session using the same variable names.

I'm trying to create a custom Authorize attribute to use the .NET session variables `authentication, userid and securitylevel` and then check against a database table to check if the user has permissions to access the section of the site.  I want to be able to use this custom attribute in place of `[Authorize]` to lock down my controllers and views as required.

I'm unsure where to begin here as I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and c#.

Comment: Do the ASP.NET & ASP classic run in the same domain?   If so you can just create the session cookie in ASP.NET after they have authenticated there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this.  I created a custom attribute that inherits from [Authorize] and inside it I set some custom logic to interrogate the session to check for prior authentication.  I will create a model for the individual rights at each site the user is attached to and will interrogate the database for those rights rather than reading in from the session.